# .NET: same entity class between Web and Web Service are conflict?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, class

This is my solution structure, there are 3 projects
.NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2010 Environment
1. Library project, use to define plain class (only have attribute, no any method) name as "Entity"
2. Web Application Project name as "MyWeb"
3. Web Service Project name as "MyServices"

**Problem**
I define Message class in "Entity"

```
namespace MyUtil
{
    public class Message
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is code to call web service method from "MyWeb".

```
MyServices service = new MyServices();
MyUtil.Message message = service.GetMessage();
```

I can't compile. It's still notify error 
cannot convert MyUtil.Message to MyWe.MyWebService.Message

So here is work code

```
MyServices service = new MyServices();
MyWeb.MyWebService.Message message  = service.GetMessage();
```

The problem is I can't use MyWeb.MyWebService.Message (the return value from web service) to passing data into another webmethod.

So I need to know, How to use same Entity class between Web and Web Service. It can't be cast to each other. This is very hard to use, any solution to solve it?

For my lastest research I found that I must define all Entity as share type, here how 
http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-share-objects-types-between-multiple-web-services/

I've tried many times and no any class on output folder. Did any one found this problem? and how to fix it.
Looking forward for help, thank you.

Comment: I guess you are using the "old school" webservices? In that case when you reference the Web Service Visual Studio generates proxy classes for you which are not the same as you used on the WebService project. If you don't have too many objects you could try to Map them with Automapper for example.

Comment: Yes, I use an old school web service. There are more than 200+ classes on my project, so if I use auto mapper the next problem is my server memory will not enough. 

Is new web service version will help me to fix this problem?

Comment: The number of classes will not that much increaste your memory. But the number of active objects will. I don't see a big issue with memory. I'm not a big expert on WCF (new web service version) so I don't know how it's solved there. However I did a project with Web.API. That works good as the data is transmitted as Json and I would used Json.NET to serialize/deserialize the data into my common classes.

Comment: thank you I think so that. I will try send/receive data by using json, it's good idea. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could define an implicit/explicit operator in MyWeb.MyWebService.Message that allows you to cast the Type from one to another.
If we assume your other Type looks the same you can put it like that:

```
public static explicit operator MyUtil.Message(MyWeb.MyWebService.Message other)
{
      return new MyUtil.Message
      {
          Key = other.Key,
          Message = other.Message,
          Value = other.Message
      };
}
```

and then just cast your type:

```
MyUtil.Message message = (MyUtil.Message)service.GetMessage();
```

You can also get rid of the cast if you use implicit instead of explicit operator.
But I wouldn't recommend that, because it may be confusing in the future of the program.
Of course the simplest method would be to just write a conversion function.

Comment: or you could just make a generic method and copy properties of the one object to new instance of the other one with the same names so that you would not have to write out all the properties that the class has and that code could be reusable for later

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code that just cloned property values from one object to the other (if the names are the same, you could also check for the type of the proeperty)

```
public TCloned CloneProperties<TSource, TCloned>(TSource sourceObj)
{
    var propertoiesToClone = typeof(TCloned).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
    var clonedInstance = (TCloned)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TCloned));

    var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (var prop in propertoiesToClone)
    {
        var appropriatePropery = sourceProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == prop.Name);

        if (appropriatePropery != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(clonedInstance, appropriatePropery.GetValue(sourceObj));
        }
    }

    return clonedInstance;    
}
```

and use it like this

```
MyUtil.Message message = CloneProperties<MyWeb.MyWebService.Message, MyUtil.Message>(service.GetMessage())
```